# Use Illustrator SVG xml in HTML

Tags: html, image, svg, tags

i have the following svg saved on my database:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 23.0.3, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  --> <svg version="1.1" id="Livello_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"    viewBox="0 0 283.46 141.73" style="enable-background:new 0 0 283.46 141.73;" xml:space="preserve"> <image style="overflow:visible;" width="512" height="512" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAgAAAAIACAYAAAD0eNT6AAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAAAlwSFlz AAALEwAACxMBAJqcGAAAABl0RVh0U29mdHdhcmUAd3d3Lmlua3NjYXBlLm9yZ5vuPBoAACAASURB VHic7d170L1XVR/w78qN3CAECJAQCAEVuQgoWEQtRXRQsCh4GxXHC6LSQqsyOmrVYgvOUJViW0sL YrW2UBRHLRZQgaJFsKVqQSDINdzviUICCSRh949zEpJffpf3vp7z7s9n5p1J/lork7PP893r2c95 aowR2K2qOj/JB7r7gAk8cozx0u4m2HwndTfAoXG37gZgEtYae0IAYK/cvbsBmIS1xp4QANgrdiVw MKw19oQAwF7xpQQHw1pjTwgA7BVjSTgYAgB7QgBgr/hSgoNxVlXdobsJNp8AwK5V1VlJ7tjdB0zE xI1dEwDYCxd3NwCTMXFj1wQA9oLdCBwsa45dEwDYC3YjcLCsOXZNAGAv2I3AwbLm2DUBgL1gNwIH y5pj1wQA9oIvIzhY51fVGd1NsNkEAHalqk6KpwCgg+DNrggA7NadkpzW3QRMSABgVwQAdsthJOhh 7bErAgC7ZRcCPaw9dkUAYLfsQqCHtceuCADsll0I9LD22BUBgN2yC4EeF1dVdTfB5hIA2C27EOhx i6yewoEdEQDYsao6J8ltu/uAiQng7JgAwG748oFebsGxYwIAuyEAQC9rkB0TANgNuw/oZQ2yYwIA u2H3Ab2sQXZMAGA37D6glzXIjgkA7IbdB/S6XVXdsrsJNpMAwI5U1SlJ7tLdB2AKwM6c0t0AG+su 6fv83GOM8dam2nBUVfXJJGc2lL5bktc11GXDmQCwU13j/88meVdTbTieS5vquhXHjggA7FTX2PF9 Y4zPNNWG43lHU123ANgRAYCd6tp1vLOpLpxI12fTBIAdEQDYqa5dR9cuC07EBICNIgCwUyYAcFNd n82LqurkptpsMAGAnTIBgJvq+mx6JJcdEQDYtqq6bZJbNZU3AWCp3pXVUyodnANg2wQAdqLzy8YE gEUaY3w6yfubygsAbJsAwE50jf//boxxeVNt2AoHAdkYAgA74QAgHJ1HAdkYAgA74QAgHJ0JABtD AGAnTADg6EwA2BgCADthAgBH1/UZvXVV3aapNhtKAGBbquq0JHdqKm8CwNJ1fkZNAdgWAYDtujh9 nxsTABZtjHFZko83lXcOgG0RANiurl3GNUne21QbtsM5ADaCAMB2dX3JvHuMcV1TbdiOrkmVAMC2 CABsV9eY0f1/NkXXZ9UtALZFAGC7unYZ7v+zKUwA2AgCANtlAgDH1/VZvfP6KR3YEgGA7TIBgOPr +qyelOSiptpsIAGALauqOyY5s6m8CQCb4j1Jrm2q7RwAWyYAsB1eAwwnsH5a5d1N5Z0DYMsEALaj a3fxkTHGlU21YSe8FIjFEwDYDi8Bgq3xY0AsngDAdjgACFvjUUAWTwBgOzwCCFtjAsDiCQBshwkA bE3XZ/bsqrp9U202jADAllTVmUnObypvAsCm6fzMOgjIlggAbNXFjbVNANgoY4wrkny0qbzbAGyJ AMBWde0qrkrywabasBteCsSiCQBsVdeu4tIxxmiqDbvhSQAWTQBgqzwBANtjAsCiCQBslScAYHtM AFg0AYCt8iuAsD1dn93zq+qMptpsEAGAE6qqSt9TACYAbKquz27nemWDCABsxZ2S3KKptgkAm+oD Sa5uqu02ACckALAVXYeKRpJLm2rDrqyfXun6/DoIyAkJAGxF127i/WOMrh0U7AUHAVksAYCt8Agg 7IxHAVksAYCt8Agg7IwJAIslALAVHgGEnen6DF+8fnoHjkkAYCu6xokmAGy6rs/w6UkuaKrNhhAA OK6qulWS2zWVNwFg012a1dMsHdwG4LgEAE6k80vEBICNtn6K5QNN5R0E5LgEAE6kKwBcMcb4WFNt 2EtdkywTAI5LAOBE3P+H3en6LJsAcFwCACfiCQDYHRMAFkkA4ERMAGB3TABYJAGAEzEBgN3p+iyf V1VnN9VmAwgAHFNVnZzkoqbyJgAcFp2fZbcBOCYBgOO5S5JTmmqbAHAojDE+muSKpvJuA3BMAgDH 07V7uDbJu5tqw35wEJDFEQA4nq7dw3vGGNc21Yb94CAgiyMAcDwOAMLeMAFgcQQAjscjgLA3TABY HAGA4zEBgL3R9Zm+aP00D9yMAMDxmADA3uj6TJ+a5M5NtVk4AYCjqqrbJDmnqbwJAIfNu5Nc11Tb OQCOqusZb5av80vjr6qqsTwcKndL8j+7m2B5TAA4FoeH4HCwljkqAYBjMTaEw8Fa5qgEAI7FrgEO B2uZoxIAOBa7BjgcrGWOSgDgWOwa4HA4t6rO7W6C5REAuJmqOi3Jhd19AHvGFICbEQA4mrvGZwMO ExM9bsaXPEdjtwCHizXNzQgAHI0vCzhcrGluRgDgaIwL4XCxprkZAYCjsVuAw8Wa5mYEAI7GbgEO lztX1andTbAsAgBHY7cAh8vJSS7qboJlEQC4iaq6Q5KzuvsA9pzJHjchAHAku384nKxtbkIA4Ei+ JOBwsra5CQGAIxkTwuFkbXMTAgBHskuAw8na5iYEAI5klwCHk7XNTQgAHMkuAQ6ns6vqvO4mWA4B gBtU1RlJzu/uA9g3pgDcQADgxi5OUt1NAPvGhI8bCADcmN0BHG7WODcQALgxuwM43KxxbiAAcGO+ HOBws8a5gQDAjRkPwuFmjXMDAYAbszuAw+2Cqjq9uwmWQQAgSVJVldVTAMDhZZ1zAwGA612QxM4A Dj+TPpIkp3Q3wGJ03RscSc4cY1zdVB9aVNUlSe7ZUNo5AJKYAPA5XbuCD7j4M6l3NtU1ASCJAMDn dO0K3tFUF7p1ffZNAEgiAPA5XbuCrl0QdDMBoJUAwPW6vhRMAJhV12f/4vVTP0xOAOB6XWNBEwBm 1fXZ99ZPkggAJKmqWybpek+4CQCzujSrp2A6uA2AAECS3i8DEwCmNMa4KskHm8o7CIgAQJK+AHDF GOOjTbVhCbomYCYACAAkcf8funStARMABACSeAIAupgA0EYAIDEBgC4mALQRAEhMAKBL1xq4fVWd 1VSbhRAAJldVJye5qKm8CQCz61wDbgNMTgDgzklObaptAsDUxhgfSXJlU3m3ASYnANC1C7guybub asOSeCcALQQAunYB7xljXNtUG5bEWwFpIQDgLYDQywSAFgIAXbsA9/9hxQSAFgIAJgDQq2stXFRV rgET8z8fvwEAvbrWwmlJLmyqzQIIABOrqnOTnNtU3gQAVt6d1VMxHdwGmJgAMLfOQ0AmAJBkjHFN kvc2lXcQcGICwNy60v/lY4yPN9WGJfJOAA6cADA39/9hGbwVkAMnAMzNWwBhGTwKyIETAOZmAgDL 4MeAOHACwNxMAGAZukLxbarq1k21aSYATKqqTk3fM8AmAHBTXgvMgRMA5nVRkpObapsAwI2MMf4u yeVN5QWASQkA8+oa/38myfuaasOSeRSQAyUAzKsr9b9rjPHZptqwZB4F5EAJAPPyFkBYFhMADpQA MC9vAYRlMQHgQAkA8zIBgGXpCsd3qapTmmrTSACYlwkALEtXOD45q6eCmIwAMKGqun2Ss5vKmwDA 0b0vq6dkOjgHMCEBYE6d9/xMAOAo1k/HvKupvHMAExIA5tS12D80xvhUU23YBN4JwIERAObkACAs k7cCcmAEgDl9XlNd4384vq418vlNdWkkAMypa7GbAMDxmQBwYASAOZkAwDJ1rZEzq+qCpto0EQAm U1W3SnJeU3kTADi+zpDsNsBkBID5dO3+k+StjbVh8cYYn0zy3qbynd8NNBAA5tOV8i8fY3ysqTZs krc11RUAJiMAzKdrkb+9qS5smq614hbAZASA+QgAsGxdZ2VMACYjAMyna5E7AAhb0xWWBYDJCADz 6RrzmQDA1nStlbOq6o5NtWkgAEykqs5Ocoem8gIAbE3ntMw5gIkIAHPpHPEJALAF60cBP9RU3m2A iQgAc+la3FeMMT7SVBs2kYOA7DsBYC7eAgiboWti5p0AExEA5nJOU13jf9ierjXT9R1BAwFgLmc0 1TUBgO3pWjOnN9WlgQAwl67F7S2AsD1da6Zrk0ADAWAuXYv7yqa6sKmuaKprAjARAWAuXYv70011 YVN1rRkTgIkIAHPpWtwCAGxP15oxAZiIADAXEwDYDCYA7DsBYC4mALAZTADYdwLAXEwAYDN8pqmu ADARAWAuJgCwGbrWzKlVdXJTbQ6YADCXrnTftZuBjTTGGEmuaSpvCjAJAWAuJgCwORwEZF8JAHNx BgA2h4OA7CsBYC4CAGwOAYB9JQDM5aruBoAtG011fU9MQgCYy+VNdc9rqgub7HZNdS9rqssBEwDm 0rWwb99UFzZSVZ2T5BYNpa8aY1zdUJcGAsBcuiYAd2iqC5uqKzTb/U9EAJhLVwAwAYDt6QrNXd8R NBAA5uIWAGyGrjUjAExEAJiLWwCwGbrWjFsAExEA5mICAJvBBIB9JwDMxRkA2AwOAbLvBIC5dC1u twBgexwCZN8JAHMxAYDNYALAvhMA5tK1uM+uqjObasMmMgFg3wkAc+lc3PdurA0bo6pOT3K3pvIm ABMRACYyxvhEkmuayj+wqS5smvslOaWptgAwEQFgPm9pqisAwNZ0rZVrk7yjqTYNBID5/HVTXQEA tuYBTXXfMsb4dFNtGggA8+kKAPeqqjOaasMm6QrLXd8NNBEA5tO1yE/J6t4mcAzrp2Xu1VT+9U11 aSIAzKcz5bsNAMd3/yQnN9U2AZiMADCZMcb703fSVwCA4+tcIwLAZASAOTkICMvUdQDwsvXmgIkI AHPqCgD3rKqzmmrDJnAAkAMjAMypa7GflOSLm2rDolXV2Um+sKm8ADAhAWBOnad9H95YG5bsYen7 ThYAJiQAzOlNSa5rqv1NTXVh6TrXhgAwoRpjdPdAg6p6c/rGjfcYY7y1qTYsTlWdkuQjSc5tKH9d kluOMa5qqE0jE4B5dSb+xzTWhiX6qvRc/JPkbS7+cxIA5vV/Gmu7DQA31bkmOr8LaCQAzOuljbW/ tKoubKwPi1FVJyV5dGMLnd8FNBIAJjXGeHOSS5vKV3q/8GBJvjzJHZtqX5fkj5tq00wAmNtLGmu7 DQArnWvhz8cYf9tYn0YCwNw6A8BDquq2jfVhKToDgPH/xASAub0yydVNtU9O8g1NtWERquoBSS5q bKFzE0AzAWBi60d/XtnYwrc21oYl+JbG2h8cY7yusT7NBAA6dwBfW1Wf31gf2lTV6Uke39iC8f/k BAA6A8BJSX6ksT50+u4kt2usb/w/OT8FTKrqb5Lco6n8p5LceYxxeVN9OHBVVUkuSd/PcV+b5LZj jE801WcBTABIencCZyb5ocb60OER6bv4J8mrXfwRAEiSFzfXf1JVndbcAxykJzfXN/5HACBJ8qok VzbWvyDJtzfWhwNTVfdL8tXNbQgACAAkY4zPpH8K8KPN9eGgdO/+3zrGeGNzDyyAAMD1ntNc//5V 9bDmHmBfVdX56Z92da91FkIA4HqvTPK25h66d0aw356UpPO8y6eT/EZjfRZEACBJMlbPg3bvDB5Z Vfds7gH2RVWdleQJzW38zhjjsuYeWAgBgBv7jax2CF0qyS801of99JNJbtPcw7Ob67MgfgiIm6iq 5yf5juY2HjHG+MPmHmDPVNVdk7w5yemNbVwyxrh3Y30WxgSAIy1hh/DMqjq1uwnYQ89I78U/Wcba ZkFMALiZqnpzen+lLEmePMZ4ZnMPsGtV9dVJXt7cxlVJLhhj/F1zHyyICQBH030YMEmeUlXndTcB u1FVpyT5N919JPktF3+OJABwNP85ydXNPZyT5Oebe4Dd+kdJlnDf3fifm3ELgKOqqv+S5Lua2/hs kgeOMf5fcx+wbVV1uyRvTXJucyuvH2Pcv7kHFsgEgGNZwo7hpCxjfAo78bT0X/yTZaxlFsgEgGOq qjckuU93H0m+fYzxW91NwFZV1f2T/GX6N1lXZnX474rmPlig7g8ny/bU7gbWfqmqlrCTghOqqpOT PCvL+H59pos/x7KEDyjL9cIkS7j/fmGSX+tuArboKUke3N1Eksuz+v0BOCoBgGNavx/gn3X3sfaY qnpidxNwPFX10CQ/3d3H2tPHGB/vboLlcgaAE6qqP03ykO4+snpPwYPGGK/vbgSOVFW3TfL6JHfq 7iXJB5J83hjjqu5GWC4TALbip7obWLtFkhes36oGS/PrWcbFP0me6uLPiQgAnNAY4zVJ/kd3H2tf mORXupuAG6uqf5rkUd19rL0jyXO7m2D53AJgS6rqvklel9Ure5fgu8YYz+tuAtaP/P3vrCZUS/DY Mcbzu5tg+QQAtqyqnpfkO7v7WLsiyZeMMd7e3QjzWt+O+qskX9Ddy9pfJ7n/8MXOFrgFwHb88yTX dDexdsuszgOc1t0IU/v3Wc7FP0l+xsWfrRIA2LIxxjuyrOfxH5DVFzAcuKr6wSTf093HjbxmjPEH 3U2wOdwCYFuq6oIkb09yRncvN/K0McbPdjfBPKrqm5L8dpKTu3u5kYeOMf60uwk2hwkA2zLG+ECW 94Ken6mqf9LdBHOoqocleX6WdfF/qYs/22UCwLZV1ZlZ/eDJ53X3ciMjyXeOMV7Q3QiHV1U9IMkr szqDshRXJvmiMca7uhths5gAsG1jjE8leVxWF92lqCS/WVUP726Ew6mqviDJS7Osi3+S/ISLPzsh ALAjY4xXZXk/yHNqkt+tqi/tboTDpaouTPKyJOd193KEP0nyH7qbYDO5BcCOrW8FvCHJ3bp7OcLH knzlGOMt3Y2w+arqNkleleRe3b0c4ZNJ7jvGeGd3I2wmEwB2bKG3ApLkdkn+uKqW8rvsbKj1D/28 JMu7+CfJT7n4sxsCALuyPnn8rO4+juIuWYWAC7obYTOtL/6/n+RB3b0cxRJvwbFh3AJg19ZflG9I cnF3L0fxniSPGGNc0t0Im6Oqbp/kxUke2N3LUVyV1ejfz2CzKyYA7NoY45NJvj/LuxWQrCYBr66q h3Q3wmaoqs9P8pos8+KfJD/t4s9eEADYE2OMVyb5j919HMOts7od8G3djbBsVfWgrC7+d+/u5Rhe k+X9EBcbyi0A9kxVnZ3VrYC7NrdyLCPJj40x/nV3IyxPVT0qyQuSnNndyzFcndWb/jzdwp4wAWDP jDGuTPL4LPNWQLL6saBnVNUvV5XPPjeoqh9K8ntZ7sU/SX7WxZ+95EuQPTXGeEWSn+vu4wR+OMlv V9Xp3Y3Qr6qemtXtqyX9tv+Rfi/JM7qb4HBxC4A9V1WV5IVJvrm7lxN4dZJHjzE+1t0IB6+qTk3y nCTf29zKibwxyYPXEzbYMwIA+2L9aOBrkty3u5cT+ECS7xljvLy7EQ5OVX1hkucl+ZLuXk7gsiRf Osa4tLsRDh+3ANgX60cDvzGrn+VdsguyekLgGVV1Wncz7L+qekKSv8zyL/7XJvlWF3/2iwDAvlm/ oexbsvoiW7JK8uQkr62qJf7kK3ugqs6rqhdl9fKcJR/2u96Prh+vhX0hALCv1j8V/MPdfWzR/ZL8 RVX94+5G2FtV9YisHlF9VHcvW/TcMYaf+mVfOQPAgaiqZyf5we4+tuHFSR43xvhIdyPs3PpJj19M 8qTuXrbh1UkeNsb4THcjHG4CAAdifeL6FUn+fncv2/DhJN83xnhpdyNsX1XdL8nzs8w3+R3Le7M6 9Pfh7kY4/NwC4ECMMa7J6rHA93T3sg13SPKSqvq1qjq/uxm2pqrOrqp/meS12ayL/1VZPZbq4s+B MAHgQFXV/bMacW7CIawb+2SSX0ryi+snHFiYqjo5q5dS/Yskd2xuZye+Y4zxgu4mmIcJAAdqjPG6 JN+eZNPub56V5ClJ3l5VP7C+2LAQ60N+r0/y7Gzmxf8nXfw5aCYAtKiqb0jyO0lO7e5lh96U5Med D+i1vs//S0m+pruXXfipMcbTu5tgPiYAtBhjvCjJtya5pruXHbp3VucDXra+CHGAquqCqvpPSf4q Lv6wIyYAtKqqRyf57WzuJCBJPpvkN5M8dYzxzu5mDrOqOjfJjyT5sWzeOZIjufjTSgCg3SEJAckq CLw0ya8k+aNhce2ZqvqSJE9M8h1JzmhuZy+4+NNOAGARquoxSX4rmx8Crve2JM9K8utjjI93N7OJ quoWWd0memKSL2tuZy+5+LMIAgCLUVXflFUIOKW7lz30yST/NcmvjDHe2N3MJqiquyR5QpLHJzmv uZ295uLPYggALMohDQHX+9Osbg/8/hhj6S9IOlBVVVkd5ntikn+Y5DA+Zuniz6IIACxOVX1zkhfk cIaAJPlQkpdk9b6Bl40xrmjup8X6d/ofmuTrs7ro37Wzn33m4s/iCAAsUlV9S5LnJTmtu5d9dk2S V2UVBl48xnhLcz/7qqrunNUF/5FJvjqbf5L/REZWP/LzC92NwJEEABarqr48ye9m9Zv8s3hn1mEg yZ+MMT7d3M+urH8x8cFZXfS/PskX9XZ0oD6V5HvHGC/sbgSORgBg0arqwiS/l+SB3b00+FSSP0ny uqzeZf/GJG9Zv1hpcarqpCR3T3KfrC70903ysCTndvbV5D1JvnH909ewSAIAi7e+V/zcJI/t7mUB rknylqzCwPV/b0hy6UH+7kBV3Smri/x98rkL/j1zOJ7R360/S/LNY4yPdDcCxyMAsDGq6seTPD1+ wvpoPpnkkiTvSvLx9d8ntvDPn01yqyTnrP+O9c/X//uFWV3wb30g/1Wb57lJnjjG2LSXXTEhAYCN UlVfl9UTAud09wI3cm2SJ48x/l13I7BVAgAbp6q+IMmLktyjuxdIcnmSbxtjvKK7EdgOo1Q2zhjj rUkelNWz9NDpkiR/z8WfTSQAsJHWv6//qCT/qrsXpvUHSb5sjPGO7kZgJwQANtYY47NjjJ9M8pgk H+7uh2lcneQnkjx61l9x5HBwBoBDoapum+TfJvnO7l441P48yePGGH/T3QjslgkAh8IY47IxxmOT PDrJB7v74dC5KsmTk3yliz+HhQkAh05VnZvkl5N8d3cvHAr/K8n3jzHe3t0I7CUTAA6dMcbfjjG+ J6s3zL2/ux821pVJnpTkoS7+HEYmABxqVXVOkmcm+b7uXtgor0jy+DHGu7obgf1iAsChNsb4+Bjj cUkekeS93f2weJ9I8kNjjK9x8eewEwCYwhjjD7P6DftnJ7muuR2W6UVJ7jPGeE53I3AQBACmMcb4 xBjjCVkFgRcmcf+LZPXK5a8YY3zjGMOUiGk4A8C0quqLkzwtySO7e6HF/03y02OMl3U3Ah0EAKZX VV+R5OeT/IPuXjgQb0zys2OM3+9uBDoJALBWVQ/PKgg8sLsX9sU7kjwlyX8bY3y2uxnoJgDAEarq MUmemuTe3b2wJ96f1f/PXxtjXNvdDCyFAABHUVUnJXlskp9LcrfebtihjyZ5epJnjTGu7m4GlkYA gOOoqlOSfH2SH0jydUlO7u2ILfizJM9J8jtjjKu6m4GlEgBgi6rqwiSPS/L9Se7S3A43dVmS30zy q2OMN3c3A5tAAIBtWt8eeHhWU4FvSHJKb0fTGlk9w/+rSX53jPHp3nZgswgAsAtVdYes3jPw+CR3 b25nFh9J8htJnjvGeFtzL7CxBADYA1VVSb4qq6nAY5LcorejQ2ckeXlW9/b/+xjjmuZ+YOMJALDH qurWSb4mq0ODD09y596ONtblWV30/yjJH40xvNoZ9pAAAPusqu6V5GvXfw9JckZvR4t1XZLXZn3B T/JaP9gD+0cAgANUVadnFQKuDwSz/9jQ+/K5C/7Lxxh/29wPTEMAgEbrRwuvDwMPTnJhb0f77vIk f5HPjfXf1NwPTEsAgAWpqnOS3Gv9d+/1372yecHgsiSXJHnT+u+SJG8aY3y4tSvgBgIAbIAFB4PL csRFPsklLvSwfAIAbLB1MHh7kts1lL/3GOOShrrAHjipuwFg58YYH8/q9HyHy5vqAntAAACACQkA ADAhAQAAJiQAAMCEBAAAmJAAAAATEgAAYEICAABMSAAAgAkJAAAwIQEAACYkAADAhAQAAJiQAAAA ExIAAGBCAgAATEgAAIAJCQAAMCEBAAAmJAAAwIQEAACYkAAAABMSAABgQgIAAExIAACACQkAADAh AQAAJiQAAMCEBAAAmJAAAAATEgAAYEICAABMSAAAgAkJAAAwIQEAACYkAADAhAQAAJiQAAAAExIA AGBCAgAATEgAAIAJCQAAMCEBAAAmJAAAwIQEAACYkAAAABMSAABgQgIAAExIAACACQkAADAhAQAA JiQAAMCEBAAAmJAAAAATEgAAYEICAABMSAAAgAkJAAAwIQEAACYkAADAhAQAAJiQAAAAExIAAGBC AgAATEgAAIAJCQAAMCEBAAAmJAAAwIQEAACYkAAAABMSAABgQgIAAExIAACACQkAADAhAQAAJiQA AMCEBAAAmJAAAAATEgAAYEICAABMSAAAgAkJAAAwIQEAACYkAADAhAQAAJiQAAAAExIAAGBCAgAA TEgAAIAJCQAAMCEBAAAmJAAAwIQEAACYkAAAABMSAABgQgIAAExIAACACQkAADAhAQAAJiQAAMCE BAAAmJAAAAATEgAAYEICAABMSAAAgAkJAAAwIQEAACYkAADAhAQAAJiQAAAAExIAAGBCAgAATEgA AIAJCQAAMCEBAAAmJAAAwIQEAACYkAAAABMSAABgQgIAAExIAACACQkAADAhAQAAJiQAAMCEBAAA mJAAAAATEgAAYEICAABMSAAAgAkJAAAwIQEAACYkAADAhAQAAJiQAAAAExIAAGBCAgAATEgAAIAJ CQAAMCEBAAAmJAAAwIQEAACYkAAAABMSAABgQgIAAExIAACACQkAADAhAQAAJiQAAMCEBAAAmJAA AAATEgAAYEICAABMSAAAgAkJAAAwIQEAACYkAADAhAQAAJiQAAAAExIAAGBCAgAATEgAAIAJCQAA MCEBAAAmVGOM7h5YsKr6UJI7dPcB7Mj5Y4wPdTfBMpkAAMCEBAAAmJAA16JfhAAAAIJJREFUAAAT EgAAYEICAABMSAAAgAkJAAAwIQEAACYkAADAhAQAAJiQAAAAExIAAGBCAgAATEgAAIAJCQAAMCEB AAAmJAAAwIQEAACYkAAAABMSAABgQgIAAExIAACACQkAADAhAQAAJiQAAMCEBAAAmJAAAAATEgAA YEICAABM6P8DwfJsOQQbGIMAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" transform="matrix(0.2491 0 0 0.2491 77.9528 7.0866)"> </image> </svg>
```

How can i show it a website? I mean, inside which tag or tags atttribute should i paste it in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it's already a HTML valid code, but it's better to take out this part

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 23.0.3, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
```